# WMV Files on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: video

How to play WMV files on Raspberry Pi 3 using Raspbian?

Comment: you may want [vc-1 licence key](https://swag.raspberrypi.org/collections/software/products/vc-1-license-key) for a start, then you would *play* them just as if they were mp4's or any other supported format

Comment: Have you tried both `vlc` and `smplayer`? Did you get an error message? Which one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use omxplayer to play .wmv files.

```
omxplayer filename.wmv
```

omxplayer is command-line only. If you want a GUI , try [omxplayerGUI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=75602).
Some .wmv files may contain VC-1 video. You need to buy a license for those files since omxplayer 
uses hardware decoding. You can buy the license [here](http://www.raspberrypi.com/vc-1-license-key/). You can check your files with a tool like
[MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) to see if they really contain VC-1 video . This might not be true of all .wmv files.